# Best way to optimize verilog cpu?

Tags: verilog, cpu, optimization, risc-v

I wrote a riscv core in verilog which works fine, but is slow. It can't go faster than 50mhz when synthesizing in Xilinx ise for spartan 6. I have however seen similar cores be able to go to 100mhz or even 200mhz in some cases. I'm wondering how they reach such speeds. I think my main culprit is that I made everything an if(with if's inside the if), but don't know what to replace the if's with.
Basically, I extract the op code from the instruction, then have an if else for every instruction. How would I optimize that? What do I replace the if's with to get a faster core?
Little snippet of my core to demonstrate the if's:

```
else if (op == 7'b0000011)// Load instructions
begin
  if (funct3 == 3'b010)// LW
    begin
      `dbg($display("LW"));
      addr = ItypeIMMSignExtended+rs1Reg;
      reqSize = 2;
      rw = 0;
      activate = 1;
      TA = ~oldTA;
      newCounter = counter + 1;

      validInstr = 1;
    end
  else if (funct3 == 3'b001)// LH
    begin
      `dbg($display("LH"));
      addr = ItypeIMMSignExtended+rs1Reg;
      reqSize = 1;
      rw = 0;
      activate = 1;
      TA = ~oldTA;
      newCounter = counter + 1;

      validInstr = 1;
    end
    /*...*/
end

else if (op == 7'b0110111)// LUI
begin
  `dbg($display("LUI"));
  rdReg[31:12] = UtypeIMM[31:12];
  rdReg[11:0] = 0;

  validInstr = 1;
end
```

Can anyone give me some advice on this?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, RISC-V is more of a logical structure than a piece of detailed circuit. However, the timing performance is tightly related to your implementation (the complexity of combinational cloud, the pipeline, etc.). As to your code, when generating `addr`, we have many instruction decode branches, different multi-bit addition operations, all should be done in one single cycle. And I noticed you used blocking assignment, so there're extra gates before `addr` gets latched into the next flip-flops maybe I think. (Sorry this is indeed a comment rather than an answer on how to improve the

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to be sure from your snippet, but it appears that you have a "single cycle" implementation, in which all of the activity for a given instruction happens in a single clock cycle. A maximum speed of 50 MHz is quite typical for such implementations.

To go beyond that, you need to start thinking at a lower level about the physical structure of your datapath, and the possibility of pipelining the execution of an instruction over several clock cycles.

A common structure for many RISC architectures is a 5-stage pipeline:

- instruction fetch
- instruction decode
- register read
- ALU
- register write

Of course, now you need to start thinking about what happens when there are dependencies among the various instructions that are in the various stages of the pipeline — do you simply stall the pipeline (insert NOPs) as needed, or do you implement a data forwarding mechanism in order to avoid stalls?

We have a lot more questions about [mips](/questions/tagged/mips) than about [risc-v](/questions/tagged/risc-v), but they are similar enough that looking through them will be helpful to you

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answer! My current pipeline is 3 stage: fetch, decode/reg red/exec/reg write, store. I could probably make it 4 stage by separating the decode from the rest. But if I were to split it into more parts, that would increase the frequency maybe, but also the amount of cycles needed per instruction. So doesn't that kinda cancel each other out?

Comment: No. The whole idea of pipelining is that you start and finish an instruction on every clcok cycle, but that any individual instruction takes multiple clock cycles from beginning to end, overlapped with other instructions at other stages in the pipeline. So, the number of instructions per second still matches the clock frequency (ignoring stalls), which, if you've done it right, is much higher than it would be without pipelining.

Comment: See my answer to [Pipelined Feedback Summation on FPGA, Verilog](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/511156/11683) for a fairly detailed example of a pipelined datapath. It is more specialized than a general-purpose CPU, but it does handle one data item per clock and illustrates the general concept reading data from a memory (or register file), processing it, and writing it back.